# TypeORM connection and isConnected deprecated issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs, backend, typeorm

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection } from '../../node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(connection: Connection) {
    if (connection.isConnected)
      console.log('DB connection is succesfully connected');
  }
}
```

why Connection and isConnected here is deprecated..What is wrong here to describe please answer

Answer (score 0):

[TypeORM v0.3.0](https://typeorm.io/changelog#030httpsgithubcomtypeormtypeormpull8616-2022-03-17) (which `@nestjs/typeorm@^9.0.0` uses) deprecated the `Connection` object. `Connection.isConnected` was replaced by `DataSource.isInitialized`
This is well outlined in their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L766), and should be the first place you check when you see deprecation remarks